# How to check if mongo db is running on Mac?

Tags: mongodb, macos, installation, osx-yosemite

I had installed `MongoDB` few days back on my Mac and am not sure how I installed, but now how do I check if `MongoDB` is up and running in my system?

Comment: [`top`](http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml)? Or `ps aux | grep mongod`. Anything that shows running processes. Trying to connect is also a start. I'm sensing a question within a question here.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, sorry I am new to the command terminal in mac. When I used  ps aux | grep mongod, I got the following: shettya          4000   0.0  0.0  2432772    640 s000  S+    1:11pm   0:00.00 grep mongod     , wanted to make sure if this means that mongodb is running ?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

## Quick Solution

Run the following in your Terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep mongod | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d ' '
```

This will get you the number of `MongoDB` processes running, thus if it is other than `0`, then you have `MongoDB` running on your system.

## Step-by-Step

- The **`ps -ef | grep mongod`** part return all the running processes, that have any relation to the supplied string, i.e. `mongod`, e.g. have the string in the executable path, have the string in the username, etc.
- When you run the previous command, the `grep mongod` also becomes a process containing the string `mongod` in the `COMMAND` column of `ps` output, so it will also appear in the output. For that reason you need to eliminate it by piping **`grep -v grep`**, which filters all the lines from the input that contain the string `grep`.
- So now you have all possible lines that contain string `mongod` and are not the instances of `grep`. What to do? Count them, and do that with **`wc -l`**.
- `wc -l` output contains additional formatting, i.e. spaces, so just for the sake of the beauty, run **`tr -d ' '`** to remove the redundant spaces.

As a result you will get a single number, representing the number of processes you `grep`'ed for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I ran the command and received a 14 (fourteen) altough there are no mongods running. Why?

Comment: Thats interesting, you might have another processes running, that have `mongod` in command path. Can you run `ps -ef | grep mongod` and post the output?

Comment: @bagrat can we use `pgrep mongod` this command to check that is mongodb is running or not?

Answer (score 31):

The answers combining `ps` and `grep` should always get you what you need. However, if you have a standard installation that comes with the mongo shell, an easier to remember method is to start the mongo shell

```
mongo
```

The shell will give you status of mongodb.

Comment: I was able to test it using `mongosh`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem sometime ago. Using `ps -ef` (the process status command) will show if the `mongod` or the mongodb daemon is running. But if it is not running, it will yield a 0 as the status indicating mondodb is not there.

However, if you want to check the installation via the system search on Mac, say using phrase such as mongod or mongodb, it will show the physical location of the installed directory and files starting with the searched phrase. If you get hold of this directory, you will see a bin directory, which will have binary files.